# Too much smoke compared to the source mesh size

Tags: mesh, smoke-simulation, fire

so I'm doing a scene with an F14 shooting two rockets. For a better result and for realism purposes I decided to also add a smoke simulation, but when I added it the results are this:
[image]
I tried to reduce the size of the inflow mesh, tried to decrease the surface and volume emission, but the only things that two values do are to decrease the amount of smoke, but not the "radius" of the smoke since I need a much thinner smoke but still pretty dense.

For reference, I'm using this photo:
[image]

The domain is as big as the whole scene since there multiple missiles that are been shot.

This is a photo of the source inflow mesh, a basic small circle.

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

EDIT 1
I'm messing a little up with the domain size, and the size of the smoke is actually changing, but it's pretty unpractical

Comment: Is your model static or animated? Fast forward will probably create a more realistic smoke shape... or add a Wind force field

Comment: It's totally static and there is already a wind force field that's why the smoke is not going up

Comment: have you tried increasing the wind speed/force?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 30 a strength value

Comment: A quick test shows me that increasing the wind strength from 1 to 10 makes a huge difference... May be you have some other parameters that you've set by mistake? Did you `free the bake` and `bake` your fluid simulation again?

Comment: Yes obviously. Now I'm trying to resize the wind field, I had some results but still nothing of okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see your domain covers way more volume then the rocket and the jet itself. The minimal amount of smoke rendered would be the amount contained in one voxel, looking at the shape of the smoke I'd guess you don't have enough domain divisions for such a comparatively small emitter.
[image]

If the scene is totally static and the rocket does not move, you should try scaling the smoke domain in such a way it's the smallest size possible to achieve the effects you need, as calculating empty space, just wastes processing power and relative voxel size is smaller, therefore the shape of the smoke is more precise.

To know the correct domain size try baking first with lower resolution division so you can see the general shape of the sim, than increase the resolution until you get the results you want.

If you want to emit a specific amount of smoke you can keyframe the "use inflow" box
[image]

And if you want to add more realism you could consider switching the emiter from smoke to "fire + smoke"